# Как получить данные из метабокса 'editor' в Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms

Как получить данные title и excerpt, я знаю. Но как получить данные из метабокса 'editor' - я, вообще понятия не имею. И, да, хотелось бы узнать, как это работает с записями и со страницами.

Comment: Точно так же, только вместо post_title используется post_content

Answer (score 0):

Можешь скачать ultimate shortcode плагин и там есть записи вывод. Получается по выводу там шаблоны работают сейчас нету под рукой и вот в (plugins/ultimateshotcode/template/teaser-loop.php) там будет вывод пример title content и thumbnails(картинка записи) и это самый легкий из вариантов в php коде будет. Так же пагинация и тд можно будет дописать и норм работать будет под себя можно шаблоны как хочешь переделывать бутс или уикит. Если хочешь по другому то вечером со своего компа отпишусь как чисто выводить с категории там wp_query кажется.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Почитаю про wp_query. А так хотелось бы, без плагинов

Comment: По идее по плагину тоже гляньте там упрощает просто 60% работ)

Answer (score 0):

получил этой строчкой:

`<?php echo get_post()->post_content; ?>`